# How to live stream audio from a url into an outgoing twilio phonecall?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml

I would like to make an outgoing phone call from my twilio number(A) to another phone number(B). When the call is picked up, I would like to livestream audio from a public url. How do I do this?

I've been looking at the `<stream>` verb in TwiML, but my understanding is that it only streams audio from an active phonecall. I'd like to stream audio into the phonecall.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right that the [`<Stream>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) only streams audio from the phone call to your server.

Currently there is no simple way to stream audio back into a call using a TwiML verb.

If you knew your way around a PBX and how to stream audio over SIP, then you could connect a call using [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip) and stream the audio that way.

Also, if you were making the call from a mobile application or browser, you could get access to the audio stream and send audio that way too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an outgoing call, you can simply use the Play verb.

For example:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
    <Play>https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```